# Use case diagram-boundary concept

Tags: use-case, uml

Can we add two or more boundaries in a use case diagram?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The boundary represents the system you are developing and it is an implicit internal actor. I guess it would cause much confusion, altough maybe if you name the boundaries... Most probably you want to do something which is not quite right, like for example just to show another system which interacts with your system, you should use actors instead. Can you elaborate on what purpose should multiple boundaries server for you?

Comment: Thanks, i got the answer from your explanation.

Comment: @Niki if so, consider accepting or at least accepting the answer, thank you!